# Jquery add / remove multiple attribute on select

Tags: jquery

I want to change whether a user can select only, one or multiple options in a select box based on a tick box above.
i.e. if the tick box is ticked the user can select multiple values, if not ticked they can only select one value.  What is the best way to do this using jquery?

Comment: Attach a change listener to the checkbox and edit the select's `multiple` attribute.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$("#theCheckbox").change(function() {
    $("#theSelect").attr("multiple", (this.checked) ? "multiple" : "");
}).change();
```

[**You can try it here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/DdhSF/)

Answer (score 10):

```js
$('#checkboxid').change(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#listbox').attr('multiple','multiple');
    } else {
        $('#listbox').removeAttr('multiple');
    }
})
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ynhat/WCPue/1/

Answer (score 7):

For newer jQuery setting prop instead of attr works:

http://jsfiddle.net/DdhSF/267/

```
$("#theCheckbox").change(function() {
    $("#theSelect").prop("multiple", (this.checked) ? "multiple" : "");
}).change();
```

Comment: Why does this work, and why does it work as it does? That is, when the box is checked why is the `select` element `<select id="theSelect" multiple="">` instead of `<select id="theSelect" multiple="multiple">`?  Why does setting `multiple` to the empty string remove it?  I can't find anything in the documentation to explain this behavior.

Comment: Good question, I don't have time to research it. It's annoying how these simple basic tasks can be a PITA

Comment: prop(attr, value) chould be use with boolean value, not string, so "multiple" works as true and "" works as false, http://jsfiddle.net/DdhSF/269/